# Create custom theme from scratch in wordpress without using default

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am developing a custom theme from scratch in WordPress, So i have few questions about it.

1) Is custom theme create using default theme. 
For example ( Suppose i have copied `twentyseventeen` and paste it and rename it `my_custom_theme` then after changes as per HTML in particular files (header,footer etc)

2) Should i create necessary files for theme like `(header, footer, index, style, page, function etc)`

So i want to clarify which way should i go for create a custom theme 1st or 2nd.

Someone please help me for this

Comment: Have you read the Codex? https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [underscores](https://underscores.me/)

It is a starter theme foundation setup built for that purpose, it has all the needed files templates and uses the best practices and organised code.

You will take it and build your theme from it.

There is also [understrap](https://understrap.com/) which is underscores with bootstrap styling

this will save you alot of setup and preparation time, you can delete and remove any code or any template you not using.